Open api specification 3.0 duplicate properties allowed
I have an object in OAS 3.0 POST method request body, which has two fields id and param both strings.
Ideally OAS validator should not allow below request as valid requst as id is duplicate in incoming request.
{
"id" : "1",
"id": "3",
"param" : "test"
}

But above request is no giving any validation failure.
Tried using additional properties as false. But still issue persists

IIRC, OpenAPI is concerned with the design of your endpoints, and not payload data validation (if it is, then I am mistaken and you can disregard this comment). For JSON validation there's basic JSON format compliance, such as duplicate object property names which should be handled by your platform's JSON library; but for more advanced validation you'll likely need to use  JSON Schema Validation library.
